# NextJS app with apollo switch from nodejs16 to nodejs18/20 triggers Zlib error: Incorrect header check error

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch-api, apollo, zlib

The following code used to work in NodeJS 16 (16.20.0 tested), but when trying to use it with NodeJS 18 (or the latest NodeJS 20) there's the following error:

Error:

```bash
[http] [Network error]: TypeError: terminated
[http] Error: incorrect header check
[http]     at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {
[http]   errno: -3,
[http]   code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
[http] }
```

This is the file that defines the authentication procedures and the only place I have any control regarding headers.

apollo.ts

```js
let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> | undefined;

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, response }) => {...);

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const AUTHENTICATION = toBase64(CREDENTIALS);
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: `Basic ${AUTHENTICATION}`
        },
    };
});

function createApolloClient(headers: IncomingHttpHeaders | null = null) {
    // isomorphic fetch for passing the cookies along with each GraphQL request
    const enhancedFetch = (url: RequestInfo, init: RequestInit) => {
        if (headers) {
            init.headers = {
                ...init.headers,
                cookie: headers.cookie ?? '',
            };
        }
        return fetch(url, init);
    };

    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
        defaultOptions: {
            query: {
                errorPolicy: 'all',
            },
        },
        link: from([
            errorLink,
            authLink,
            createUploadLink({
                uri: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/graphql`,
                credentials: 'include',
                fetch: enhancedFetch,
                // Make sure that CORS and cookies work
                // fetch: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? enhancedFetch : undefined,
            }),
        ]),
        cache: new InMemoryCache({...}),
        connectToDevTools: true,
    });
}

type InitialState = NormalizedCacheObject | undefined;
interface IInitializeApollo {
    headers?: IncomingHttpHeaders | null;
    initialState?: InitialState | null;
}

export function initializeApollo(
    { headers, initialState }: IInitializeApollo = {
        headers: null,
        initialState: null,
    }
): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
    const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient(headers);
    // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
    // get hydrated here
    if (initialState) {
        // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract();

        // Merge the existing cache into data passed from getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
        const data = merge(initialState, existingCache, {
            // combine arrays using object equality (like in sets)
            arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
                ...sourceArray,
                ...destinationArray.filter((d) => sourceArray.every((s) => !isEqual(d, s))),
            ],
        });

        // Restore the cache with the merged data
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(data);
    }

    // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient;
    // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;

    return _apolloClient;
}

export function useApollo(initialState = {}): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
    const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo({ headers: null, initialState }), [initialState]);
    return store;
}
```

I have a login page, that is able to fetch a cookie from the API endpoint, but then a subsequent request within `getServerSideProps` (more precisely, `apolloClient.query`) triggers the error.

#### Additional information

```js
Operating System:
      Platform: darwin
      Arch: x64
      Version: Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Mon Apr 24 20:51:50 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64
    Binaries:
      Node: 18.16.0
      npm: 9.5.1
      Yarn: N/A
      pnpm: N/A
    Relevant packages:
      next: 13.4.5
      eslint-config-next: 13.4.5
      react: 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0
      typescript: 5.1.3
```

#### Example

*No response*